# Splitting a string into substrings after a number of characters in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string which contains 80+ characters and I want to divide it into two substrings. The first one to contain the first 80 characters and the other one the next characters.

I was able to obtain the first `String`.

```
public static void SetStrings(String stringName) {
    int numOfChars = stringName.length();
    String firstString = stringName.substring(0, 80);

    int maxChars = 80;

    if (numOfChars > maxChars) {
        stringName = firstString;
    } else {
        stringName = stringName;
    }
}
```

Comment: @andrewdleach That's asking about splitting on a specific character though, not on index.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
String secondString = stringName.substring(80);
```

You should also look at the Javadoc for [String.substring(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)).

Comment: You should probably first add a line to check that `stringName` contains at least eighty characters, otherwise this will generate an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: If the string is only 79 long then `stringName.substring(80)` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. And given that the OP's method is marked `public` it really ought to validate the provided string before it operates on it. I've seen a production system fall over recently because a developer failed to check for the length of the string and assumed it would always be long enough for their new piece of code. Defensive programming doesn't cost much and tends to save a lot of time later.